# ORACLE SQL TRUNC DATE CHANGE

Tags: sql, oracle

I can't undertand why does Oracle SQL do this:

```
SELECT TRUNC(TO_DATE('05-FEB-21 15:35:32', 'DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS'), 'DAY') AS BUG FROM DUAL;
```

Yields:

| BUG |
| --- |
| 31-JAN-21 |

It is needed to enforce the `TRUNC([...], 'DAY')` so it can be filtered by day independently of hour.

Therefore, I needed the output as:

| NONBUG |
| --- |
| 05-FEB-21 |

Can someone please help?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a bug.  Just a misuse of a date format.

If you want to trunc to the day, use `'DD'` or just leave the argument off:

```
SELECT TRUNC(TO_DATE('05-FEB-21 15:35:32', 'DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS'), 'DD') AS BUG
FROM DUAL;
```

`'DAY'` (as explained in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/ROUND-and-TRUNC-Date-Functions.html#GUID-8E10AB76-21DA-490F-A389-023B648DDEF8)) is for the starting day of the week.